# Is Ghostscript free for use in a commercial App?

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am currently developping for a client a wordpress CMS which will act as webservices for a windows phone application. In this CMS, I will use ImageMagick for PHP to convert a multipage PDF to a single image. This image will then be sent to windows phone application.
The PDF will almost never changed and it is to make the operation transparent for admin of CMS. I want, when they change the PDF (which will be perhaps extremly rare), to make make it invisible for them.

My question is this : can we use GhostScript which will be used by ImageMagick without a commercial licence ?

I contacted Artifex but they weren't very helpful with their answers. They oriented me to another of theirs software. They didn't answer at all my questions.

Thanks

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, if you are conforming to the AGPL then you can use AGPL software freely. If you aren't, then you can't.

This isn't a legal site, so I doubt people will be comfortable giving you legal advice (I certainly wouldn't be, I am definitely not a lawyer), if you have concerns about your proposed use, then you should seek competent legal advice. You will almost certainly have to pay for that of course.

Comment: That's what I don't really get with licences. The CMS will not be accessible to the public, only admin and I will not make any modification on GhostScript, just use it. It's really confusing but thanks for your answer.